# How to fix error in ccavenue in split payment API

Tags: node.js

I am using split payment API in ccavenue in Node.js for vendor payment but when I am running the API from Postman,I am getting status=1&enc_response=command is mandatory. Although I am using command in request param but still I am getting error status=1&enc_response=command is mandatory. How can I resolve this issue?

I used following code:

```
  router
  .route("/split-payment-to-vendor")
  .post(asyncHandler(ccavenuePayment.splitVendorPayment));



exports.splitVendorPayment = async (req, res) => {

  const requestType = 'JSON';
  const responseType = 'JSON';
  const command = 'createSplitPayout';
  const accessCode = '';
  
  const apiUrl = 'https://apitest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans';

  const splitDataList = [
    { splitAmount: '40.76', subAccId: 'TEST01' }
  ];

  const params = {
    access_code: accessCode,
    request_type: requestType,
    response_type: responseType,
    split_tdr_charge_type: 'M',
    merComm: '2.0',
    reference_no: '',
    split_data_list: splitDataList,
    Command: 'createSplitPayout', // Include the correct command value here
  
  };

  const encryptedParams = encryptRequestParams(params);

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, {
      enc_request: encryptedParams,
      access_code: accessCode, // Include access_code in the request
      Command: params.command, // Include command in the request
    });

    console.log('API Response:', response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

function encryptRequestParams(params) {
  const paramString = JSON.stringify(params);
  const workingKey = '21236EE0F88F6E7F757A0A12B998E6EA';

  const key = Buffer.from(workingKey, 'hex');
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector, can be all zeroes for CBC mode

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(paramString, 'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

  return encrypted;
}
```